# Math operations as a variable?

Tags: javascript

I'm making a calculator with JS on a webpage and I'm wondering if it would be possible to do something like this:
I've got 5 operation buttons each like

```
<button name="operation" onclick="operation(+)">+</button>
<button name="operation" onclick="operation(-)">-</button>
```

etc

Then, in that function, I would have this:

```
function operation(n) {
  var num1 = [contents of display]
  var operation = n
}
```

Then in the equals function I would have this.

```
function equals() {
  var num2 = [contents of display]
  document.getElementById("display").value = num1 operation num2;
}
```

Is something like 'num1 operation num2' possible, or do I need lots of separate functions?

If you want to see the current state of my calculator for some reason, click [here](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GD9N4QO18IRI). (None of the purple operation buttons nor the equals button do anything yet, ofc.)

Comment: Put all the characters associated with the button in a string. When the equal button is clicked parse and evaluate then show the answer

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure what you mean as I'm pretty new to JS... could you elaborate? @DominiqueFortin

Comment: Not sure the reason why you need two functions. But after getting the string + or - from your button clicks, you simply declare the two variables in your operation function, then use the symbol to determine the sign you will use to declare the value you wish passed into the #display element in your HTML body. Try coming up with the code, then update it as an answer or let me know if you need a code sample.

Comment: You need to learn about Compilation et Automatas.  But put simply, let say you have `67+5`, you read the first character (6); is it a digit? yes, you continue.  You read the next character (7); is it a digit? yes, you continue.  You read the next character (+); is it a digit? no, so your 2 first characters are digits, so you create a variable for the results (67). The next character (+) was an operator so you that in operation variable. And so on...

Comment: @optimalresource, do you mean that I should just have a bunch of ifs, or something else? What do  you mean by 'use the symbol to determine the sign'?

Comment: @TorNato Look at [How to build an html calculator app from scratch using javascript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-build-an-html-calculator-app-from-scratch-using-javascript-4454b8714b98/)

Comment: @benterris have coded my explanation already, yes you need the if and else, but 3 would do, if +, else if - and else if some random symbol drops in. But for the context of what you doing, the if and else statements are sufficient since there won't be room for random symbols to be entered. You still need to learn the language more before tooling with it so next time you only ask really complex questions, I guess that's what others imply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `operation(+)` is not valid javascript.

If you want to proceed this way, you should use strings to determine the operation, for instance:

`onclick="operation('+')"`

And then in you function `operation` have something like:

```js
function operation(operator) {
  var num1 = ...
  var num2 = ... // whatever you do to retrieve those values
  if(operator == "+") {
    document.getElementById("display").value = num1 + num2;
  }
  else if (operator == "-") {
    ... // same for -
  }
  // and so on
}
```

Comment: This works mostly when I change 'onclick("operation('+')")' to 'onclick="operation('+')"'. Quick question though, should I keep using the 'else if' thingy? Because [this](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GD00V2ZNAY3R) isn't working @benterris

Comment: It isn't working because you're not storing the values num1, num2 and the operator between the functions. You should add something like `var num1 = null`, `var num2 = null` and `var op = null` at the top of the javascript to declare the variables, before your functions, and use these variables to store your values : for instance, in the function `go`, use `num2 = document.getElementById("display").value;` (without the `var`, because this would mean redifining the variable)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript won't accept your `operation(+)` because it is an invalid expression.

A better solution could be using a `switch case` for the operation like in this example:

```
function operation(value1, value2, operator){
    switch (operator){
        //addition case
        case '+':
            return value1 + value2;
            break;
        //subtraction case
        case '-':
            return value1 - value2;
            break;
        //moltiplication case
        case '*':
            return value1 * value2;
            break;
        //division case
        case '/':
            return value1 / value2;
            break;
        //default case (this should never happen but who knows)
        default:
            return 'err';
            break;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps ;)